# AWS - Create a new Test DB from Production DB

Tags: testing, amazon-rds

We migrated our servers to AWS last week and we got just one instance of our DB, the production. It is working fine. But now we need a copy for development and we can't just create a new one with another name using the Production DB backup (it is not allowed). Is there any way we can overcome it? We are using SQL Server 2008,

Comment: **we can't just create a new one with another name using the Production DB backup (it is not allowed)."*  It is not allowed by what mechanism?  Is there an error message?

Comment: If I try to create from the Producion DB backup, I get this:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: BACKUP LOG permission denied in database 'Producao'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)